# Surface Pro 7+ will no longer boots USB

Tags: linux, windows, live-usb, surface

I am running Windows 11 22H2 on a Surface Pro 7+. I used to be able to change the boot order in the UEFI and boot into a Linux USB and install Linux as a dual-boot. Then, when I was using Ubuntu, I found an article in Surface-Linux that I was hoping would allow me to use my integrated camera in Ubuntu. Instead, I no longer can boot into any Linux distro, it just freezes at the splash screen. I am pasting the article with the code I used, which was unsuccessful because the point where I am supposed to enter surface as a password never showed up, I restarted the computer and I then had to reformat and reinstall Windows.

First you need to import the keys we use to sign packages.

```
wget -qO - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/master/pkg/keys/surface.asc \
    | gpg --dearmor | sudo dd of=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/linux-surface.gpg
```

After this you can add the repository configuration and update APT.

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian release main" \
    | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linux-surface.list
sudo apt update
```

If you encounter any issues reading "Error 401 Unauthorized" during the update or the installation below, please have a look at this.

Now you can install the `linux-surface` kernel and its dependencies.

```
sudo apt install linux-image-surface linux-headers-surface libwacom-surface iptsd
```

Important: Support for `iptsd` only goes back to the latest LTS release at the time of writing (Debian 11 and Ubuntu 22.04). If you are using an older release, and the above command fails, then please remove `iptsd` from it. You will still be able to use basic singletouch through the kernel driver, but multitouch and the stylus will not work.

After that you can install our secureboot key. This will import the key that the `linux-surface` kernel is signed with into your bootloader, so that the kernel is bootable without disabling secureboot.

```
sudo apt install linux-surface-secureboot-mok
```

This package will print instructions to the terminal. In case you missed those: It will ask you to reboot. Then, upon reboot, a blue menu (MokManager) should pop up, asking you whether you want to enroll the key. Confirm with OK/Yes and when asked for a password enter surface. Note that MokManager expects a QWERTY keyboard layout, you may need to adjust your input accordingly. In case you missed the menu or accidentally chose the wrong options, you can uninstall (fully) and then reinstall the package and reboot to trigger the menu again.

Note that this will only work if your Debian derivative supports secure boot out-of-the-box. If not, please consult the Wiki of your distribution and set up secure boot for distro/stock kernels first. You also want to skip installing the package for now and only install it after you have set this up.

The `linux-surface` kernel will be installed alongside the default kernel provided by the distribution. This way you have a backup kernel you can use if something goes wrong. The bootloader will pick up the kernel by default, but you should update its configuration to make sure it was recognized.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue and I managed to install ubuntu using Ventoy. Just install Ventoy [here](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html). Follow the installation instructions, dont forget to select "GPT Partition Table" and just copy your iso on your USB. Then boot on your USB and select your linux.iso, "Grub2 install".